# What is the 90% confidence last hail date for Denver, Colorado?

Tags: frost, cold-weather, snow

There have been large hailstones in the city of Denver, Colorado every Spring of each year for more than 30 years.

My father and I always used the last ***frost*** date to decide when to plant my tomatos, cucumbers and other vegtables.

Half of the time, my vegtables die from being pummeled with large hailstones int he late spring or early summer.

What is the Average last ***hail*** date for Denver, Colorado?

It is usually in June or July, but I do not know exactly what day is historically the date after which only 10% of recorded hailstorms have occurred.

Comment: I am not sure that historical records can provide a 90% confidence level given the changes in weather around the world

Comment: "Last hail date" isn't even a concept, generally, since hail can happen in suitable thunderstorms (usually, but not always) throughout the summer.